# Display a List in TextView

Tags: android

I'm making a fake command-line system for a fun app, and I want to show the input and output in the same TextView, like this:

```
>something
>something else
>even more stuff
>etcetera.
```

I already figured out how to store the text from the EditText into a string and add \n and >, but I can't use strings for the whole thing: to avoid clogging up RAM, I'd like to delete lines after, say 50? I figured that would be much easier to do using Lists.

However, this doesn't work:

```
log.setText((CharSequence) logText);
```

But what will?

Comment: Erm... I don't quite understand what you meant there... Further clarification? :I

Comment: you'll have to iterate over your list to get each item (or the `toString()` method might already do this for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can put all your strings in a list, an each time you add one, recreate a single string from the list which contains all your items, and affect it to your textview.

Comment: Like this?

String logValue = logText.toString();

Comment: Nope. More like 
String logValue = ""; 
for(String item : logText)
     logValue += item;

Comment: Remember, don't use + for `Strings` if you're appending it in a loop; instead, take a look at `StringBuilder`.

Comment: because you instanciate n extras strings. StringBuilder will expand the allocated space without creating new Strings. Also, as I posted, there are methods for that, preventing us from reinventing things that simple every time, allowing to concentrate on what really matters

Answer (score 1):

This method :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.Iterable)

return a string composed of each element (either cast as a string or the toString value is used) separated by the delimiter in between each element. You can therefore easily concat all your items in one String.

You can also use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int, int)
to limit the count of items in said list.

From your question I assume logText is a List of some sort, therefore you can call

```
log.setText(TextUtils.join("\n>", logText.subList(0, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ListView` without a separator and populate it using an `ArrayAdapter`.

That way you wouldn't have to worry about memory, and the user could easily scroll through previous commands.